# Adding a Mask Overlay on top of Leaflet v0.8-dev

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, leaflet, mask

I'm trying to create a circular masked overlay using Leaflet 0.8 that is positioned over the users currently location, extending a radius of 1000 meters. Essentially making the map visible around the user (as a circle), and grayed out beyond 1000 meters

**Mockup:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv8G6.png]

As the user zooms in/out on the map, the circle should resize accordingly.

I tried using **[leaflet-maskcanvas](https://github.com/domoritz/leaflet-maskcanvas)**, a plugin for Leaflet that looks like it would do exactly what I need, unfortunately with all refactoring done in Leaflet 0.8-dev, this plugin isn't compatible.

Has anyone been able to achieve this effect successfully with Leaflet 0.8?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking of one hacky way of doing this is using Turf.js to take the map's current center point(`map.getCenter()`), buffer it 1000 meters with Turf, take that result, and then grab the map viewport's current bounds(`map.getBounds()`), and use turf `erase` on it. Then draw the resulting polygon on the map(which is the difference), and then update this on any move events.

http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_buffer.html
http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_intersect.html
http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_erase.html

Comment: Thanks @snkashis, I'm not too familiar with turf.js, but from looking at the links you provided that might do the trick. My only concern is that my app is a mobile app, and the turf.js library looks quite heavy.

Comment: Cool.Note that you can require just what you use with browserify.